# Maximum post size?

Tags: uploads

I use a form to allow users to post tutorials on my website. When there are too many pictures uploaded, it seems like the site reaches a limit and stop uploading them: the post has only the first half of the uploaded photos.

Does it mean there is a limit post size ? If yes, how can I increase it ?

Comment: Are you asking how large can a posts content be, or are you asking how many images can you attach to a post? Uploading images isn't the same as the text used as the content in a post, can you clarify?

Comment: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/  set limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't upload more that 20 pictures per post, that was the issue. I had to ask my host to modify max_file_uploads

Servers are usually set at 20 uploads at a time so if you want more, just ask your hosting service of modify it in php ini.

Answer (score 3):

Try editing the **post_max_size** variable, if you have access to your php.ini file. This variable is the limit of the entire body of the request, which could include multiple files ([source - stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15077229/5123735)).

If you don't have access to it you can try editing your functions.php file and add:

```
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M'); //this will set 64mb as limit
```

If that don't work you can try editing your .htaccess file:

```
php_value post_max_size 64M
```

If that doesn't work either, you can try creating a php.ini file in your root directory and add:

```
post_max_size = 64M
```

If that fails either you must contact your hosting company and ask them to increase the size of it.

p.s. If you have access to cPanel check out the tools there. Some hosting companies have options to edit these variables.